Docker container to container not working with firewalld enabled
I have managed to pinpoint the culprit to firewalld after I blindly updated my home lab system (I know...), but I cannot understand what's wrong here.
I can reproduce it by issuing the following commands:
docker network create --driver bridge mytestnet
docker run --net mytestnet --name terminal_a -it busybox sh
docker run --net mytestnet --name terminal_b -it busybox sh

Then
sudo systemctl stop firewalld.service

Pinging from inside the container to the other peer works. If I enable it, it stop working.
This is my firewalld config:
➜  ~ sudo firewall-cmd --list-all-zones
block
  target: %%REJECT%%
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces:
  sources:
  services:
  ports:
  protocols:
  forward: yes
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports:
  source-ports:
  icmp-blocks:
  rich rules:

dmz
  target: default
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces:
  sources:
  services: ssh
  ports:
  protocols:
  forward: yes
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports:
  source-ports:
  icmp-blocks:
  rich rules:

docker
  target: ACCEPT
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces:
  sources:
  services:
  ports: 8681/tcp 8688/tcp 8088/tcp
  protocols:
  forward: no
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports:
  source-ports:
  icmp-blocks:
  rich rules:

drop
  target: DROP
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces:
  sources:
  services:
  ports:
  protocols:
  forward: yes
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports:
  source-ports:
  icmp-blocks:
  rich rules:

external
  target: default
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces:
  sources:
  services: ssh
  ports:
  protocols:
  forward: yes
  masquerade: yes
  forward-ports:
  source-ports:
  icmp-blocks:
  rich rules:

home
  target: default
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces:
  sources:
  services: dhcpv6-client mdns samba-client ssh
  ports:
  protocols:
  forward: yes
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports:
  source-ports:
  icmp-blocks:
  rich rules:

internal
  target: default
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces:
  sources:
  services: dhcpv6-client mdns samba-client ssh
  ports:
  protocols:
  forward: yes
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports:
  source-ports:
  icmp-blocks:
  rich rules:

public (active)
  target: default
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces: enp3s0
  sources:
  services: dhcpv6-client http https ssh
  ports: 51821/tcp 51820/udp 29811/tcp 29812/tcp 29813/tcp 29814/tcp 27001/tcp 29810/tcp 27001/udp 29810/udp 8043/tcp 6881/udp
  protocols:
  forward: yes
  masquerade: yes
  forward-ports:
  source-ports:
  icmp-blocks:
  rich rules:

trusted (active)
  target: ACCEPT
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces: docker docker0
  sources:
  services:
  ports:
  protocols:
  forward: yes
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports:
  source-ports:
  icmp-blocks:
  rich rules:

work
  target: default
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces:
  sources:
  services: dhcpv6-client ssh
  ports:
  protocols:
  forward: yes
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports:
  source-ports:
  icmp-blocks:
  rich rules:

My networks as follows:
➜  ~ ip -br a
lo               UNKNOWN        127.0.0.1/8 ::1/128
enp3s0           UP             10.25.0.2/24 fdb4:bae2:8828:0:dabb:c1ff:fea3:3ce8/64 fe80::dabb:c1ff:fea3:3ce8/64
wlo1             DOWN
br-84890f73c571  UP             172.19.0.1/16 fe80::42:14ff:fe64:bfb9/64
br-ea26a9614db1  DOWN           172.25.0.1/16
veth6534ad7@if261 UP             fe80::4cbc:b6ff:fe62:2eda/64
br-004896b076a6  DOWN           172.22.0.1/16
br-2383e0587680  DOWN           192.168.112.1/20 fe80::42:82ff:fec6:473f/64
veth6dde112@if263 UP             fe80::c8b7:2ff:fed8:36da/64
br-5128e227e901  DOWN           172.20.0.1/16 fe80::42:95ff:febd:103b/64
vethf6ae1e5@if265 UP             fe80::2c4a:c8ff:fe27:bd96/64
br-08512b34f5ad  DOWN           192.168.176.1/20 fe80::42:c1ff:fe6e:9a/64
br-2d859e1b7e06  DOWN           172.21.0.1/16
vethd142ea2@if267 UP             fe80::bc49:dcff:fe58:e7d8/64
br-59281aac5d89  DOWN           192.168.32.1/20
br-ec3b9c42c686  UP             172.29.0.1/16 fe80::42:e0ff:fe82:21ae/64
veth368f538@if269 UP             fe80::78cf:dfff:fe23:5aeb/64
br-281213661d1e  UP             172.18.0.1/16 fe80::42:3bff:fe5b:9c5c/64
docker0          DOWN           172.17.0.1/16 fe80::42:c1ff:fec4:651f/64
veth6866d17@if271 UP             fe80::247f:8fff:fe6e:a453/64
br-eaa21af1f323  DOWN           172.28.0.1/16 fe80::42:a8ff:fe1f:3115/64
veth4fb5022@if273 UP             fe80::9c7c:31ff:fef2:b712/64
vethdb8b802@if275 UP             fe80::6cb3:40ff:fe44:25b6/64
vethd1fe5b5@if277 UP             fe80::3056:7dff:fe08:1672/64
vethb92ebda@if279 UP             fe80::64f3:edff:fedf:7ea/64
veth7f983c5@if281 UP             fe80::60da:56ff:feb5:d7ab/64
veth236bdc0@if283 UP             fe80::404:9aff:fe0d:a178/64
veth26975a0@if285 UP             fe80::4049:1cff:fe04:1b59/64
veth1459960@if287 UP             fe80::b893:51ff:fe27:8b71/64
vethee0fb91@if289 UP             fe80::a87d:f0ff:feeb:fc0d/64
vethf6e9ce5@if291 UP             fe80::9845:8cff:fe7f:d1cb/64
vethfdc233d@if293 UP             fe80::308b:7fff:fef1:73b8/64
vethcf4f829@if295 UP             fe80::e4db:2bff:fe7d:f54b/64
wt0              UNKNOWN        100.127.130.228/16
veth983b2ab@if316 UP             fe80::5c21:89ff:fe4c:67f7/64
br-c7fcbd01b75b  UP             172.23.0.1/16 fe80::42:55ff:fecb:9fa0/64

iptables is disabled:
➜  ~ iptables -L
zsh: command not found: iptables

For reference, my setup was working before I blindly upgrade all packages. These were the affected packages:
base-files bash bind9-dnsutils bind9-host bind9-libs bluez bluez-obexd containerd.io distro-info-data
  docker-buildx-plugin docker-ce docker-ce-cli docker-ce-rootless-extras docker-compose-plugin krb5-locales less
  libaom3 libc-bin libc-dev-bin libc-devtools libc-l10n libc6 libc6-dev libdav1d6 libfreetype6 libglib2.0-0
  libglib2.0-data libgnutls30 libgssapi-krb5-2 libk5crypto3 libkrb5-3 libkrb5support0 libltdl7 libnss-systemd
  libpam-systemd libpython3.11 libpython3.11-minimal libpython3.11-stdlib libseccomp2 libssl3 libsystemd-shared
  libsystemd0 libudev1 linux-image-amd64 linux-libc-dev locales nano netbird openssh-client openssh-server
  openssh-sftp-server openssl python3-idna python3.11 python3.11-minimal systemd systemd-sysv systemd-timesyncd
  udev zsh

I'm a bit lost on how to debug this
